# Is there a Unity-like global menu applet for gnome-panel?

Tags: gnome, unity, indicator

In the top panel of Unity there's the Title of the window, and when it's moused over, a global menu pops up. Is there a similar indicator for 10.10?

I've found the Indicator Applet Appmenu and Window controls for the panel, but I'm looking for one that works similar to the titlebar/global menu indicator. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The only part that is handled by the indicators is the menus themselves.  The window title and the window controls are all handled by Unity itself.  So to do that specific effect you'd need to write an applet that did it.

But, there was something similar done on UNE back when it used GNOME Panel.  You might be able to use the applet there and get some of the same effect.  Or at least start you on your path.

Comment: It would be a neat thing to update the panel applet which supports the Unity global menu to do the same appname / menu dance that Unity does in 11.04. As Ted says, that code would be your best starting point.

Comment: "Window Applets" can add those buttons or the window title on the top panel: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/window-applets-0210-released.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot is this one:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/install-gnome2-globalmenu-in-ubuntu.html