# Is it possible to blend the new Natty app bar with Ubuntu classic?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Unity-like global menu applet for gnome-panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22846/is-there-a-unity-like-global-menu-applet-for-gnome-panel)

I know this is an odd question. I like the top and bottom panels of Ubuntu Classic, but I also like the Natty app bar as well. Is there a way to blend the two? I know... why do I need the bottom bar if I have the app bar? Old ways die hard, thats why :) I also like the old top panel feature of "Applications | Places | System" ... yet all that said, Id like to have the new dock (ok, not dock, but Natty app bar).

I would think this blending of old and new would be a great way to transition long time users who are, uhhhh, nervous of change :)

Any tips or ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put 'gnome-panel' at start up applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [Places Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/42432#42432) that would bring back one of you missing items.